# Multiple definitions for a variable

Tags: c

Why doesn't the following code give an error as i is defined multiple times as int i=10? Further,why isn't the iterating variable i affected? Why is there no conflict ? The output is 1010101010. How?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        int i=10;
        printf("%d",i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Automatic variables are alive only in the scope `{`,`}` in which they reside.
You have two variables named `i` in your program:

- The `i` declared in `main` has scope of entire `main` function.
- While the `i` inside the `for` loop has scope only inside the loop.

Note that when you refer `i` inside the for loop the inner `i` **shadows** the `i` declared in the `main`.

Comment: What about the output? Why is it 1010101010?

Comment: @PrithviRaj, You increment the inner `i` and then it gets destroyed and recreated next iteration. Thus, the `i` printed is `10` all five times.

Comment: @PrithviRaj: Inside the for loop the compiler sees only the `i` declared inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`int i=10;` in `for loop` is only available inside the loop it doesn't know if it was previously defined outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Scope of variable defined within a block of code is limited to that block only.
ie.,

```
int i=1;//outer i
{
int i=2;//inner i
printf("%d"&i);// this ll print 2
}
printf("%d"&i);// this ll print 1
```

same in for too., ie

```
int i=1;
for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
printf("%d",&i); // print 0 1 2 3 
}
printf("%d",&i); // print 1
```

In your case every time you initializing inner i to 10 and printing it then you incremented inner i, so it everytime prints value of inner i you declared and initialized to 10

Answer (score 0):

this is because of scope of variable

scope of variable lies within { to }

your first int i will be alive through out the main() while the int i inside for will be alive inside for loop only.

now why the output is 1010101010???

the simple explanation is when you enter for look your new i will be equal to 10, you print it then i++ makes it 11. again next time i = 10 you print it and i++ makes it 11 this continues for main() int i < 5 so five times you will get 1010101010.

hope it helps.....